# Getting Error Text 'Time' could not be parsed at index 0 in when i'm trying to parse time

Tags: java, date, apache-poi, java-time

I'm trying to retrive date cell from my xlsx sheet in java and tying to formate the data in "MM/dd/yyyy" formate

```java
Cell celldate=row.getCell(2);
    String value=formatter.formatCellValue(celldate);
    CellType type=celldate.getCellType();
    String dat=value;
    if(dat!="") {

        DateTimeFormatter inputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a");
        // Parsing the date
        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(dat,inputFormat);
        // Format for output
        DateTimeFormatter outputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
        // Printing the date
    System.out.println(date.format(outputFormat));
```

but getting error Text 'Time' could not be parsed at index 0

xlsx sheet

[image: my xlsx sheet]

and when i'm writing the same data as written in sheet it's working

```java
    Cell cellname=row.getCell(7);
    String stname=cellname.getStringCellValue();
    Cell celldate=row.getCell(2);
    String value=formatter.formatCellValue(celldate);
    CellType type=celldate.getCellType();
    String dat="12-09-2023 10:08 am";
    if(dat!="") {

        DateTimeFormatter inputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a");
        // Parsing the date
        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(dat,inputFormat);
        // Format for output
        DateTimeFormatter outputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
        // Printing the date
    System.out.println(date.format(outputFormat));
```

Comment: Looks like you try to parse *Time*? Please add always the complete stacktrace to the question

Comment: are you sure the pattern is correct? It could be formatted by excel to be shown in that way, but without formatting it looks different. Please open the excel in a csv(notepad) to see it without formatting

Comment: yes it is written in same formate

Comment: oh wait lmao, I just saw it. What Jens said is correct. You are trying to parse your header columns "Time". The only solution? dont.

Comment: how can i avoid my header column from parse

Comment: ???? just dont? if the index is 0 (or 1 if apache poi is not zero indexed) dont parse it?

Comment: or check if the string .equals("Time")

Comment: As an aside `dat!=""` will not work. [Java String compare](https://www.javatpoint.com/string-comparison-in-java) on TutorialsPoint.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My error is resolved by adding this line

```java
    Iterator <Row>rowiterator =sheet.iterator();
    Row headerRow= rowiterator.next();
```

This “consumes” the header row containing the string `time`, which obviously cannot be parsed as a date and time, and thus prevents that the code following will try to do that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).